# What can be specified for QUERY within Graph API search

Tags: facebook-graph-api, search, syntax

I am looking for a description of the syntax and semantics that govern what can be put in QUERY; where the syntax provided for search is

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=QUERY&type=OBJECT_TYPE